# MS Teams Beta with Adaptive Card showing 'sent a card' in the summary

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Looking for some help in regards to adaptive cards with the new MS Teams beta (Version: 23202.1509.2295.2283.).

The issue I am having is when our adaptive card gets sent the summary is not coming through and is instead being displayed as 'Sent a card' vs. the summary we have set for it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l65xU.png)

Where as being on MS Teams classic (version: 1.6.00.22904) the issue is not present.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKZsw.png)

I'm hoping someone may have the answer as to why these are different in terms of the versioning and if there is a solve for this issue.

Below is the code used to create the adaptive card:

```
        public override Attachment Attachment()
        {
            Attachment attachment;
            if (PostImageId.Length == 6)
            {
                var card = new ThumbnailCard
                {
                    Title = PostTitle,
                    Subtitle = string.Join(", ", PostTags),
                    Text = PostDescription,
                    Images = new List<CardImage>(),
                    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                };
                card.Images.Add(new CardImage { Url = PostImageSource }); ;
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TeamsUrl))
                {
                    card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction
                    {
                        Type = "openUrl",
                        Title = "Open in Teams",
                        Value = TeamsUrl.Replace("null", $"%22post%7C{PostId}%7C{PostSourceId}%22")
                    });
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SPUrl))
                {
                    card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction
                    {
                        Type = "openUrl",
                        Title = "Open in SharePoint",
                        Value = $"{SPUrl}?postId={PostId}&sourceId={PostSourceId}"
                    });
                }
                attachment = card.ToAttachment();
            }
            else
            {
                var postCardAttempt = (AdaptiveHeroCardTeamsAttempt)this;
                attachment = AdaptiveCardHelper.GetHeroCard(postCardAttempt);  
            }

            return attachment;
        }
```

And the code that adds the adaptive card with the summary:

```
       public async Task<SendResult> SendAsync(NotificationTeamsAttempt attempt)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attempt.ConversationId))
                    throw new Exception("Conversation Id is required.");
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attempt.ServiceUrl))
                    throw new Exception("Service Url is required.");

                using (var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(attempt.ServiceUrl), _clientId, _clientSecret))
                {
                    var activity = MessageFactory.Text("");
                    activity.Attachments.Add(attempt.Attachment());
                    activity.Summary = attempt.Summary();
                    var response = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(attempt.ConversationId, activity);
                    return new SendResult
                    {
                        IsSuccess = true,
                        DispatchId = response.Id
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return new SendResult
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Exception = exception
                };
            }
        }
```

Attempted to send a different adaptive card which ended with the same result as the last.
Swapping to the 'classic' client solves the issue, but going back to the beta the issue continues

Comment: We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update.
Microsoft Teams version 23217.806.2340.1703.

Comment: Hello @Shootex - This issue is fixed internally but not publicly released yet.
We don't have Exact ETA to share but will let you know once it is released publicly.

Comment: Issue is resolved in Teams2.1. Could you please check and confirm the same.
You have Microsoft Teams version 23306.3311.2542.4729.
You've got the latest version. It was last updated on 1/12/2023.
The client version is 49/23110231807.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMq7A.png